# Send Object from Fragment to Main Activity without starting Activity

Tags: android

In my app Main Activity is the base of Fragments. now i want to send only data( object) from fragment to activity( this activity contains all fragments ) without staring activity. Here is my code which is used in fragment and activity respectively

Fragment Code:

```
public void sendData()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),UHFMainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_BUTTON_VALUE", btSearch.getText().toString());
        getActivity().setIntent(intent);
    }
```

Main Activity Code:

```
public void receiveData()
    {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String SCAN_BUTTON_VALUE = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_BUTTON_VALUE");
    }
```

Comment: you can create a public method in activity to psot data from fragment to activity. No need of opening activity again.

Comment: Or you can create an interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
((UHFMainActivity)getActivity()).sendData(yourObject);
```

in your activity

```
public class UHFMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void sendData(Object object){
//        todo do your stuff with object
    }
}
```